# Azure Machine Learning Studio -getting error in consumption of endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, azure, endpoint, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have deployed a machine learning model as a pickle file in azure machine learning. The endpoint is created. Now, I am trying to consume the endpoint through the following codes:

```
import requests
import numpy as np

# send a random row from the test set to score
random_index = np.random.randint(0, len(X_test) - 1)
input_data = '{"data": [' + str(list(X_test[random_index])) + "]}"

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

resp = requests.post(service.scoring_uri, input_data, headers=headers)

print("POST to url", service.scoring_uri)
print("prediction:", resp.text)
```

It's giving error with following message:

```
prediction: {"data": "Expecting value: line 1 column 12 (char 11)", "message": "Failed to predict"}
```

The data looks like:

```
X_test =>  array([[[0.   ], [0.274710], [0.403273]]])

'{"data": [' + str(list(X_test[random_index])) + "]}"     
convert it to 
'{"data": [[array([0.]), array([0.274710]), array([0.403273])]]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current code mentioned, it was mentioned as POST method. But to consume the endpoints, it was suggested to use the GET method.

```
import requests
import os
import base64
import json 

personal_access_token = ":"+os.environ["AZ_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
headers = {}
headers['Content-type'] = "application/json"
headers['Authorization'] = b'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8'))

#Get a list of agent pools.
instance = "dev.azure.com/name"
propVals = "{name=Default,isHosted=false}"
api_version = "version _number”
uri = ("complete uri”)

r = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
```

To get the complete URI, use the GET method with `poolName` embedded into the syntax

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?poolName={poolName}&api-version=5.1
```

If the case is like using the `POST` method itself, change the below line in the 6th line of the code.

```
input_data = '{"data": [“ + str(list(X_test[random_index])) + "]}’
```

The **single and double quotations are misplaced**.